# Why does FxCop insist on IDisposable for a struct

Tags: c#, fxcop

I have the code similar to the following in one of my projects:

```
internal enum ArtworkType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Bmp = 1,
    Gif = 2,
    Jpeg = 3,
    Png = 4
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct TagArtwork
{
    internal IntPtr data;
    internal int size;
    internal ArtworkType type;
}
```

When I run FxCop on this code, I get run into warning [CA1049](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182173.aspx). This struct is used for interoperability with a native code library, so it pretty much **has** to have this layout. Why does FxCop give me grief about this struct? I have other structs in the same source file, which also have `IntPtr` members, but FxCop does not complain about those.

For example, the following code does **not** trigger the same warning:

```
internal enum ItemType
{
    Implicit = 0,
    Utf8 = 1,
    Utf16 = 2,
    Sjis = 3,
    Html = 6,
    Xml = 7,
    Uuid = 8,
    Isrc = 9,
    Mi3p = 10,
    Gif = 12,
    Jpeg = 13,
    Png = 14,
    Url = 15,
    Duration = 16,
    DateTime = 17,
    Genres = 18,
    Integer = 21,
    Riaa_pa = 24,
    Upc = 25,
    Bmp = 27,
    Undefined = 255
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct MP4ItmfData
{
    internal byte typeSetIdentifier;
    internal ItemType typeCode;
    internal int locale;
    internal IntPtr value;
    internal int valueSize;
}
```

I suppose I could implement `IDisposable` on the struct, but that just seems wrong. Likewise, I could simply suppress the warning, but at the moment, I want to understand what it is about this particular struct that is triggering the warning, when it's not that much different than the other seven structs I have in the same source file. Alternatively, I'd happily accept an explanation of why the other structs **don't** trigger this warning.

Comment: just suppress the warning, unless you're the one *allocating* the unmanaged handle, in which case you should implement IDisposable.

Comment: I realize I could simply suppress the warning, but I want to understand what makes **this** struct so special. I'll edit the question to make it clear that I don't want to suppress the warning in this case.

Comment: Could you post the code for another struct which also has an IntPtr and doesn't trigger an FxCop warning?

Comment: @Scott Done with the most recent edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Code Anylsis engine produces this warning any time you have a managed type that includes a member of what it considers a "native" type. To be a native type, the field must:

- Be `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr`, or a `HandleRef`
- Not be `static`
- *Actually be assigned a value from native code*

I'm pretty sure that this third bullet is probably the difference between your various structures. The analysis engine (based on a quick dotPeek perusal) will only trigger the warning if it actually finds an instance of your `IntPtr` being assigned from native code. I haven't yet found exactly what it considers an "assignment from native code" but whatever that is, my best guess is only one of you various `struct` types is triggering that part of the rule.

Note that this is based on reading the actual code of the *current implementation* of the Code Analysis engine as ships with VS2010. It is absolutely **not** a documented behavior of the rule, but likely a specific optimization to reduce false positives. You should not assume that code which currently "passes" this rule (e.g. because it's never assigned from native code) will always do so, as MS is free to change the implementation details at any time.

As mentioned in my comment, suppressing the message is a perfectly legitimate response in this case; this is not one of the FxCop rules that should never be suppressed. The rule is very context-specific and only applies if you're *allocating* a native resource of your own. If you are only passing the struct back and forth between C# and unmanaged code, then you can most likely just suppress the warning and move on.

Comment: That's exactly it, actually being assigned from native code. What documentation page did I forget to read where those bullet points are laid out?

Comment: they are not. I ran dotPeek on the code analysis assemblies and traced through it. Which I should point out in my answer.

Comment: It seems rather odd that the warning would be applied to a struct, since there's no way a struct can actually "own" anything.  It would make sense for the analysis engine to make note of structures that contain such types, and suggest that any class which contains fields of those structure types should implement `IDisposable`, but having a structure type include a non-trivial implementation of `IDisposable` would seem a pretty severe anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite clearly spelled out in the article you linked:

> This rule assumes that IntPtr, UIntPtr, and HandleRef fields store pointers to unmanaged resources. Types that allocate unmanaged resources should implement IDisposable to let callers to release those resources on demand and shorten the lifetimes of the objects that hold the resources.

So just the plain appearance of IntPtr in the struct is enough to trigger the warning.  After you verified that you *really* didn't forget to release the native resource, apply the [SuppressMessage] attribute on the struct to not have to look at this message again.

Comment: But that's exactly my point. I have literally seven other structs, in the same project, five of which also contain `IntPtr` members. None of them trigger the same warning. Yes, I read the documentation; no, I don't understand how one struct triggers the warning, but the others don't.